# Newline not showing correctly in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, string, textbox

I am loading a `string` from my database which among other things contains line breaks (`\r\n`). However, this isn't being rendered as a new line but instead as `\r\n`.

If I type it directly in instead of loading it from a string, it works just fine but I need to be able to load it from a string.

Any ideas?

Edit: Upon closer inspection, it looks like the string is being returned as:

```
Changed test7\\r\\nChanged test8\\r\\nChanged test9Changed test7
```

From the database.

I tried running a `.Replace(@"\\", @"\")` on it but this had no effect at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work `.Replace("\\", "\")` because it sees the backslash as an escape, but strangely, this doesn't work when it should: `.Replace(@"\\", @"\")`

The one that I got to work is this:

```
.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

Comment: I still don't understand how it works, but it does. Shouldn't `\\r\\n` translate to `\r\n`?

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
string yourString="something\r\n..somethingMore";
yourString=yourString.replace("\r\n",Environment.NewLine);
yourTextBox.Text=yourString;
```

Does this solution meet your requirements?

Comment: Thx for formatting my answer @competent_tech, still getting used to it :)

Comment: Silly me! I forgot to quote the string to be replaced, this should work 
yourString=yourString.replace(@"\r\n",Environment.NewLine);

Thanks for pointing it out to me mate :)

Answer (score 2):

Call `.Replace(@"\r", "\r").Replace(@"\n", "\n")`

or just `.Replace(@"\r\n", "\r\n")`

Answer (score 1):

Is the Multiline property on your TextBox set to true?

Answer (score 1):

When you call your `.Replace` function, you're appending your strings with `@`. By doing so, your `@"\\"` gets converted to `"\\\\"` and your `@"\"` gets converted to `"\\"`.

Try running `.Replace("\\", "\")`, and it should work.

Comment: That doesn't work because the `\` gets countes as an escape character.