# Newline data not showing up correctly in vb.net multiline TextBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, textbox

I'm populating a multi-line TextBox from MySQL, and the data is basically paragraphs with multiple lines with line breaks in between. My data looks fine in the database; when I copy and paste the data into a text editor (I use NotePad++) directly from workbench, the data looks fine.

[image]

There's a curious space between Test2 and Test3, but I can live with that.

When I try and MsgBox it, it looks fine too:

[image]

But when it comes to adding it to my TextBox, my problem comes:

[image]

I've looked at several resources, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968954/newline-not-showing-correctly-in-textbox), but I couldn't find a solution that worked, nor a reasonable explanation why this is happening. Does anyone at least have an explanation so I can figure out a workaround?

Comment: Which one [of the three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27223228/11683) is your data using?

Comment: Does it work if you use a RichTextBox instead of a TextBox?

Comment: @Jimi, my good sir, it does indeed. Thank you so much!

Comment: That means that you're carrying over `\n` (`VbLf`) instead of `\r\n` (`VBCrLf`). RichTextBox uses `\n` as the new line char, while the TextBox control needs both (Windows style).

Comment: In notepad++ Click View>Show Symbols>Show All Chars What is being show for your line spaces?

Comment: @Jimi perhaps you might want to include that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, from the text pasted into Notepad++, that the original string copied from [MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), contains multiple line feed chars and, probably, a space which separates the text parts.

This becomes more evident, since a MessageBox shows the text separated in multiple lines.
The [.Net MessageBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MessageBox.cs,484) wraps the [User32 MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) function, which allows `\n` (`VbLf` - `CharW(10)`), `\r` (`VbCr` - `CharW(13)`) or both (`VBCrLf`) as line separator(s).
The string parameter of the message part, **`lpText`**, will parse and adapt any of these:

> The message to be displayed. If the string consists of more than one
>   line, you can separate the lines using a carriage return and/or
>   linefeed character between each line.

A standard TextBox instead requires that a LineFeed+Carriage Return (`\r\n`) are used to separate lines of text: when the text is pasted in a TextBox control, since only `\n` is used, the text is not separated in different lines.

The RichTextBox control is more *international* (MacOs also ditched `\r` for the *nix `\n`): it uses `\n` to separate lines of text.
If we provide `\r\n` (Windows style) as line separator, the control converts `\r\n` to just `\n`.
Thus, pasting this text in a RichTextBox, the original line feeds are parsed as intended.